# Linear-Regressing Y on X : Interpreting coefficient 1

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I did a (multi)linear regression of Y on a collection $X_1, X_2,..,X_k$ of variables.

Some of the coefficients of the $X_i $ were very close to 1. Can I conclude that Y and $X_i$are , in a sense, equivalent to each other (adjusted $R^2$ was also pretty high)?

The standard interpretation of the coefficient $b_i$ of $X_i$ I am aware of is that a change of 1 unit in $X_i$ results in a change of $b_i$ units in Y. Now, if $b_i$ is close to 1, this says a change of 1 unit of $X_i$ results in a change of 1 unit in Y, so that, in a sense, $X_i$ does not provide any information about Y, it is in a sense equal to Y. Is this correct? If so, is there a way of making this more precise?

Comment: If you have multiple variables and all coefficients are 1, this implies Y is best approximated by the sum of all the variables, not by any individual one.

Comment: @josliber: but what if the restricted regression coefficients Y|X_i , i.e., restricting to a single regressor and , are also close to 1, and each having a high R^2 ? Doesn't that imply each X_i itself is somehow equivalent to X?

Comment: In simple linear regression if you have an intercept of 0, coefficient of 1, and high R^2 then yes the outcome is well approximated by the single variable. However, your question is written about multivariate analysis, not simple linear regression with a single variable. If you are asking about simple linear regression, please update your question accordingly.

Comment: No, I meant Y|X_i , where the regression in question is Y|X_1, X_2,..,X_k , i.e., I am referring to a multiple regression restricted to a single variable and getting the given results: high R^2 and a coefficient close to 1.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "multiple regression restricted to a single variable"? Do you mean you are noticing that one of the variables has coefficient 1 from among all the variables in a multivariate model, or are you fitting a new linear regression model with just that single variable?

Comment: I mean I am considering the original regression with all the coefficients set to 0 except the coefficient a_i of the variable X_i. Say I want to find Y:=salary in terms of  X_1:years of employment,   X_2: years of education, X_3 :Number of certifications. I obtain Y=b1x1+b2x2+b3x3. Now I just want to consider  Y in terms of years of, say, X2-- years of education, and I find that  b2 is close to 1 with small intercept. Can I conclude that X2 is a sort of proxy for Y , so that X2 is redundant in the initial multivariate model?

Comment: I means that, if $x$ increases by an amount, then $y$ increases by the same amount.

Comment: @fcop: Yes, but this seems to imply that Y and X are interchangeable and X provides no information on Y in the sense that X is , in some way, a copy of Y.

Comment: @MSIS: well if a change in X implies a same change in Y that does not mean that they are interchangeable does it ?  It am pretty sure that the change in my age over time will be the same as the change in your age over time, but are our ages 'interchangeable' ? Also, it holds only when ''all other things are equal'' and it depends on the units of X and Y

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, just because a coefficient value is close to 1 in multiple linear regression does not imply that the variable is almost equal to the outcome. Consider a simple example:

```r
(dat <- data.frame(y=c(1.1001, 2.1002, 3.0997, 4.0001, 4.9999), x1=c(.1, .1, .1, 0, 0), x2=1:5))
#        y  x1 x2
# 1 1.1001 0.1  1
# 2 2.1002 0.1  2
# 3 3.0997 0.1  3
# 4 4.0001 0.0  4
# 5 4.9999 0.0  5
```

In this dataset, the outcome variable y is basically equal to the sum of the two independent variables x1 and x2; as expected the linear regression has an excellent R^2 and both coefficients are close to 1:

```r
summary(lm(y~., data=dat))
# Coefficients:
#              Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept) 0.0009000  0.0005079    1.772    0.218    
# x1          0.9950000  0.0031623  314.647 1.01e-05 ***
# x2          0.9998000  0.0001095 9126.884 1.20e-08 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.0001732 on 2 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:      1,   Adjusted R-squared:      1 
# F-statistic: 1.569e+08 on 2 and 2 DF,  p-value: 6.376e-09
```

However, not only is variable x1 not "in a sense equal" to y, but it is actually negatively correlated with y (correlation coefficient -0.857).

---

On the other hand, if you fit a regression model using a single variable and it has coefficient close to 1, intercept close to 0, and high R^2, then indeed you can conclude that the variable is very similar to the outcome.